# Prometheus not showing eclipse java server as up

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to use prometheus and for that this is my proetheus.yml file

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

  # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
      monitor: 'codelab-monitor'

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first.rules"
  # - "second.rules"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'my_job'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080']

# The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'node'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100']
```

I start the `node_exporter` service running on port 9100 and my java server in eclipse as well. But prometheus says that the node job is up (1) while my_job is not (0). Why might this be happening? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Is your java server producing a valid /metrics on that port? Here's one guide to setting it up: https://www.robustperception.io/instrumenting-java-with-prometheus/

Comment: You mean hitting localhost:8080/metrics. Authentication is needed to access the webserver. Is that why prometheus is failing?

Comment: Probably. Configure Prometheus with appropriate credentials.